# Домен сайта c точкой на конце

Tags: веб-программирование

Добрый вечер!

Можно ли создать сайт, к примеру, с доменом `google..com`?

То есть домен `google.` вместо `google` (на конце точка и потом ещё одна точка от com, ru и т. д.)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> В домене допустимы следующие символы:
>
> Можно использовать буквы, цифры
> и «-» (дефис, минус), регистр символов значения не имеет.
>
> Минимальная
> длина имени домена - 2 символа, максимальная — 255 символов (с точками
> и именем домена первого уровня).
>
> Имя домена не может начинаться или
> заканчиваться на дефисы или содержать два дефиса подряд. В именах
> доменов обычно используются латинские буквы.
>
> В имени домена можно использовать и кириллицу, при переключении клавиатуры.

То есть ответ: нет, создать домен с точкой нельзя.